# Python can't find "__main__" module

Tags: python, discord

When I try to run my code I get this error: `\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: can't find '\_\_main\_\_' module in ''`

I have no idea how to fix it. I have looked at similar posts to mine but their fixes did not seem to work. Here is all my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.client()

@client.event  
async def on_ready():
    print(f"we have logged in as {client.user}")

client.run("my bot token would be here")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):  # event that happens per any message.

    # each message has a bunch of attributes. Here are a few.
    # check out more by print(dir(message)) for example.
    print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")


client.run(token)  # recall my token was saved!

@client.event
async def on_message(message):  # event that happens per any message.
    print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")
    if str(message.author) == "hello" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('hi')
```

Comment: Have you installed discord lib? And python?
Can you give more information about your environment and execution?

Besides, I strongly recommend you to change to a Unix environment.

Comment: discord lib and python are both installed. i am using sublime text so i just code and run and it does the rest for me. i am quite new to coding

Comment: Please post the full traceback. We need the details.

Comment: i'm not too sure what you mean, all my code is right there. here is the full error if you meant that. C:\Users\zorbs\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ' '

Comment: @NoHaxJustEncrypted - Interesting. That suggests that the script never ran and the problem is with your installation.

Comment: yea i fixed it, turns out i forgot to put the code in the right folder. i am so annoyed but its all apart of coding

Answer (score 1):

Very simple fix. You have included two client.events. discord.py does not allow for this and people end up getting the most random errors. I have had this issue for a while as well. You need to specify what the discord bot is looking for. here is the adjusted code that you can change based on your needs.
At the end of your code, you need to add `await client.process_commands(message)` as that will make sure the bot considers all possibilities, and your commands, as well as events, will work.

```py
import discord

client = discord.client()

@client.event  
async def on_ready():
    print(f"we have logged in as {client.user}")

client.run("my bot token would be here")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):  # event that happens per any message.

    # each message has a bunch of attributes. Here are a few.
    # check out more by print(dir(message)) for example.

    if " " in message.content: #Basically it'll work if the message contains " "
        print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")

    if str(message.author) == "hello" in message.content.lower(): #This is good because you are specifying what the bot should be looking for ("hello")
        await message.channel.send('hi')
    await client.process_commands(message)


client.run(token)  # recall my token was saved!
```

another possibility: The client.run should be at the end of your code and at the end only. remove it from the on_ready function, it is not needed there.